# How to center a list of Auto-Sized items on screen in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, layout

[image]

This image shows what I want to achieve, but without putting a hard width on the list of items (in code it's on the pancakeview).
I want the popup to be displayed in the center of the screen, sized to it's content (providing that the screen is wide enough)
I've tried multiple things: stacklayout, collectionlayout ... and arrived at the flexlayout with a fixed width and custom selection logic.
There is the option to calculate the max label width and calculate it in codebehind, but that seems overkill for a scenario like this.

```
<Grid   FlowDirection="{Binding MyFlowDirection}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="InputGrid" >
            <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="30" BackgroundGradientAngle="20" BorderThickness="5" BorderColor="{StaticResource LightColor}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" Padding="0,20,0,40" Margin="0,0,0,50" WidthRequest="400">
                <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="SettingsScrollView" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" Margin="5">
                    <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" Direction="Column" Wrap="NoWrap" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:DataType="viewModels:LanguageSelectionBookLanguageChoiceViewModel" >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                        
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>                                                                                
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Orange" IsVisible="{Binding Selected}"></Grid>                                    
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="64" WidthRequest="64" Source="{Binding FlagImage}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding Name}" FlowDirection="{Binding FlowDirection}"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  IsVisible="{Binding Selected,Converter={converters:InverseBoolConverter}}" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Name}" FlowDirection="{Binding FlowDirection}"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkColor}" IsVisible="{Binding Selected}" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </FlexLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </yummy:PancakeView>
            
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,10"  Source="checkmark_greenblue.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

if I remove the hard width it stretches to full width:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you **don't** specify a hardcoded width? (To clarify exactly how the current code doesn't work as desired.)

Comment: Thinking about this more, it won't be possible, using standard controls. During page layout, the layout manager is not able to predict width needed by individual items in the ItemTemplate - it doesn't have access to that information. You would have to write a custom layout class, with custom renderer code on each platform, to calculate width needed. This is an advanced topic. Easier hack: in code behind, calculate **approximate** width, by finding length of longest string. This is only approximate, because different characters have different widths.